# In SVN, is it true that usually a branch is only touched by one developer?

Tags: svn

From what I have understood, a branch is directly copied from trunk.

Say we have developer A and B. A wants to work on the project, so he creates branch1 and copies trunk to branch1. He then works in Branch1. Is there a scenario where B would want to work in branch1 as well?

It seems to me that if B wants to work on the project, he would create branch2 from trunk instead of working on the same branch.  Is this the spirit of SVN?

Comment: Two developers working on the same development branch isn't functionally different than two developers both working on trunk; the same issues would apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not true.

A branch can be copied of every repository subtree. But in most cases it's a /trunk or some other branch.

> Say we have developer A and B. A wants to work on the project, so he
>   creates branch1 and copies trunk to branch1.

Creating a branch operation is a copy itself. It creates a branch which points to the trunk. It's called "cheap copies", a concept which is similar to symlinks.

> He then works in Branch1.
>   Is there a scenario where B would want to work in branch1 as well?

Yes, it's a common scenario. For example, the branch is a *feature branch* and multiple developers can be working on it.

> It seems to me that if B wants to work on the project, he would create
>   branch2 from trunk instead of working on the same branch. Is this the
>   spirit of SVN?

It depends on the particular case and a branching model you use. It's totally OK for A and B to work on the same branch.

Comment: Thank you!! Since I was testing it out by myself, I got a feeling that a branch is for one developer. I actually have seen the word "feature branch" several times, but kept forgetting it since I don't have much experience in it. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Thenewstockton check the doc: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html